# How to Get all Collection where Collection Name like '%2015%'

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I have collections in MongoDB with name has Year

for example 
I have three  collections

2015-Sam

2015-John

2014-Sam

How to get a list of

2015-Sam

2015-John

using Mongodb query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `getCollectionNames` method and `filter` them using a regular expression:

```
> db.getCollectionNames().filter(function (c) { return /^2015\-/.test(c); })
[ "2015-foo", "2015-foo1" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MongoDB 3 or up, you can use [db.listCollections](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/listCollections/) with a filter on the collection's name. If you're using 2.x, then you would have to filter on the complete list as Ionica pointed out.